# Date is displaying 3 days before now in Nodejs based site that is hosted in Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, digital-ocean

Inside the messages model we have:

```
createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
```

field which should display the correct date. While we sent a message it showed 04.10 instead of 07.10. The project is hosted in Digital Ocean. Back-end is built with Node.js Express and Mongo DB. What is wrong and how can we fix the date?

Comment: try changing default to Date.now

Comment: changing to what?

Comment: It's already set date.now

Comment: Date.now() to Date.now

Comment: It's a system date. ssh to the VM and update it. See https://serverfault.com/questions/461752/ntpdate-and-ntpd-failing-to-sync-clock-on-linux

Comment: After setting the date as @AlexBlex suggested, I would also suggest to run `ntpd` or similar to ensure the dates are kept up to date.